# Need to insert new rows into a different table when a form updates

Tags: ms-access

I'm working in a database (which I didn't design) and I'm running into a problem I can't solve. The database is used to report on productivity metrics for accountants at a property management company (ex. if the manager runs the report for 5/1/14, it returns the list of properties that each staff accountant was assigned as of that day) as well as what the assigned points (1 point for cash-based accounting, but 2 points for accrual-based accounting, etc.) were for each property.

Now my boss would like to be able to archive the points values for each property so that when the reports are run, they report on whatever the values were on that particular day, even if the values for the property have since changed.

The first problem I've run into is that most of the database is dependent on the property's ID number (this is used company-wide) being the primary key so I had to create a new "archive" table with the primary key being an auto number so that a property can have multiple rows of data.

Property values are updated in a form. When the form is updated, I need the original table to be updated with the new values (this is what happens now) but also for a new row to be inserted into the "archive" table with the all of the form's data. Then, I'll just have to re-do the report queries to direct to the archive table and add another date filter.

Does anyone how I can make this insert/copy thing happen?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm confused - what data is the archive table actually holding? Updated records or the old property value (which has since been updated?)

Comment: Hi!  It's going to be holding everything that the main table has, plus (hopefully) all the new data as well.  So, the main table will have the current property record values (that will change whenever the form is updated - that's what happens now) and the archive table will have the current values in one row (the one I need to figure out how to insert when the form is updated) but also all the old data in other rows that will NOT be updated, ever.  Is that any more clear?  I was kind of handed something that is an awful mess.  :-(